# How to detect disconnection in websockt by using boost::beast?

Tags: c++, boost, websocket, boost-beast

I know I can use the error code in `async_write`, `async_read` to check the disconnection.

However, in my situation, after I receiving something, I cannot write back immediately (or write back may never happens).

> During the time between reading and writing, how can I check the
>   client disconnetion exception?

Answer (score 5):

> I know I can use the error code in async_write, async_read to check the disconnection.

Actually only `async_read` will inform you if the other end closed the connection gracefully.

> During the time between reading and writing, how can I check the client disconnetion exception?

You can't. In fact, it is not always even possible to know if the other end closed the connection, even if you are calling `async_read`. You need to use a timer to time-out the connection if there has been no activity for a while. You can use the ping function of the websocket stream if too much time elapses with no activity. This is demonstrated in the advanced server examples.